# Why does my matDialog not render correctly with Angular v15?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular15

so recently I updated my project to version 15 of Angular. I followed the guide from the official Angular documents, however, ever since I removed my entryComponents, my MatDialog does not open correctly. I have since also transformed every component I had to standalone. Everything up to the Dialog components works.

In my console I only get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errorState')". However, even removing and creating a fully new MatDialog component does not seem to remove this error. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I really do not know from where this could come from :?

```
TS Button to open Dialog:
openAddPhonenumberDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddPhonenumberComponent, {
      minWidth: "300px",
      autoFocus: false,
    });
}

TS PhonenumberComponnet
Component({
  selector: "app-add-phonenumber",
  templateUrl: "./add-phonenumber.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./add-phonenumber.component.css"],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    NgIf,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
})

HTML PhonenumberComponent
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add a new phonenumber</h2>
<form [formGroup]="addPhonenumberForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddNewPhonenumber()">
    <mat-dialog-content style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Phonenumber</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="phonenumber" type="tel" required 
                (input)="formatInput()">
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close] (click)="close()">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="result" >Save</button>  
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

My package.json:

```
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^16.1.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^16.1.8",
    "@angular/animations": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~15.2.9",
    "@types/gapi.client.drive": "^3.0.8",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xstate": "~4.6.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
```

Picture of how it looks like right now:

[image: dialog displays matform wrong]

Comment: image not display in your question

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below method :

```
    <div mat-dialog-content style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Phonenumber</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="phonenumber" type="tel" required 
                (input)="formatInput()">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close] (click)="close()">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="result" >Save</button>  
    </div>
```

I have use `div` tag and use `mat-dialog-content` & `mat-dialog-actions`  as a attribute. I my case same problem solve with this way.

Comment: Sadly this does not resolve the display, I still get the native looking form field and no buttons

Comment: can you please confirm that you have added material theme css ?

Comment: I have tried with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nue8pb-uvduae?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html